# How to store regex in dictionary python?

Tags: python

How to store regex inside dictionary. I have a text file stored in my computer and I wanna go trough it line by line. I need to use regex to get some information. So far I'm good. My problem is I do not know how to store it in dictionary. Only the information that I need, not the other stuff that comes with it.
I want to safe the data in key while value how many time appeared
input syslog.log ... output email address and how many time appeard

Comment: Why do you need to store it in a dictionary at all?  Why not a plain string?

Comment: one of requirements

Comment: can you show some sample data?

Comment: @Raju_Komati the data that i want from the txt file i wanna sotre it the the key while in value how many time the data repeated

Comment: you need to elaborate

Comment: @rafi in question you said you want to store `regexp` and now you want to store data in txt file and how many times it's repeated. Give some clarity and show how the data stored in txt file?

Comment: @Raju Komati .. for example u have test.txt and u wanna go trough line by line ..then u have to use regex to find for example email address. after that u need to save the email address in dictionary and how many time appeared

Comment: @rafi I understood i have to gothrough line by line in txt file what i'm not getting how the data arranged in txt file and if you want to get answer to your question you need to add sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below approach first read the file and create empty dictionary. An for each line check if that line is alreday in dictionary increment the value else intialize the value with 1.

```py
d = {}
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for data in fp.readlines():
        data = data.strip()
        if data in d:
            d[data] += 1
        else: 
            d[data] = 1

print(d)
```